# Domanassa & Dukkha in enlightened beings?

Tags: dukkha, comparison

What is the difference between domanassa & dukkha? Does domanassa arise in enlightened beings? Does bodily dukkha arise in enlightened beings?

Answer (score 5):

> **OP: What is the difference between domanassa & dukkha?**

There are many classifications of feelings:

[image]

[Vedanā (Feeling)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.3-Khandha-2-Vedana-piya.pdf)

According to the 5-fold classification, a distinction is made between mental and physical pain and pleasure.

[image]

[Vedanā (Feeling)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.3-Khandha-2-Vedana-piya.pdf)

In this classification, physical pain (Kāyika dukkha) is called simply dukkha and mental pain (cetasika dukkha) is called domanassa. Kāyika dukkha and cetasika dukkha are also dukkha, hence classified as such in 3 fold classification.

> [Dukkha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dukkha) - General Application, & various views regarding dukkha. As simple sensation (: pain) & related to other terms: (a) principally a vedanā, sensation, in particular belonging to the body (kāyika), or physical pain (opp. cetasika dukkha mental ill: see domanassa).
>
> [Domanassa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dukkha) - Domanassa means unpleasant feeling in mind. lit. 'sad-mindedness', grief, i.e. mentally painful feeling (cetasika-vedanā), is one of the 5 feelings (vedanā, q.v.)
>
> **OP: Does domanassa arise in enlightened beings?**

No. An enlightened person feels Dukkha (Kāyika dukkha) but not Domanassa:

> Bhikshus, when the instructed noble disciple is touched by a painful feeling, he does not sorrow,
> or grieve, or lament, or beat his breast, or become confused. So he feels (only) one feeling: the bodily, not
> the mental.

[Sall’atthena Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/5.5-Sallatthena-S-s36.6-piya.pdf)

> **OP: Does bodily dukkha arise in enlightened beings?**

Yes. An enlightened person feels Dukkha (Kāyika dukkha) but not Domanassa:

> Bhikshus, when the instructed noble disciple is touched by a painful feeling, he does not sorrow,
> or grieve, or lament, or beat his breast, or become confused. So he feels (only) one feeling: the bodily, not
> the mental.

[Sall’atthena Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/5.5-Sallatthena-S-s36.6-piya.pdf)

Comment: this seems spot on, and i'm surprised it was downvoted. though i guess a reference for 'Domanassa' would be useful (not a word i recall seeing before)

Comment: @user3293056 I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you have framed this question, it seems that you already know the difference-- as you are using words dukkha, domanassa and `bodily`-dukkha. Again, it seems main purpose is to know the different thinking of different minds regarding their presence in enlightened ones. ---:)

`Straight answer to the presence of any dukkha whether it's daurmanasya or bodily-dukkha or unsatisfactoriness`- **NO**.

`Dukkha is a term that is being used in 1st Noble Truth`

**Dukkha** :: A broader term used by buddha as a base and concrete word to explain that ,`"Whatever happens outside this body or inside this body -- if it generates sankharas within this body"` is called as dukkha `within`. It is a very wide term that is being used for all living beings on Earth and every other realms(if one believes in them).

**Domanassa** or **Daurmanasya** to be precise :: A term which is a subset of dukkha. This specific word relates to that part of dukkha where perception gives the final approval of pain in various forms such that these forms might persist `within` even when there is no pained physical sensation, i.e. these forms have their own separate identity other than pain_perception from physical sensation. For it is generally arisen by(but not limited to) `8 worldly concerns` and may vary from person to person.

For eg., Childhood friends talking in abusive language will not give them daurmanasya whereas, if I(a stranger) go to them and start abusive language-- it may cause them daurmanasya if they would have been expecting respectable language from me.
Another Eg. :: Two friends who are used to share even same underwears since childhood, now have grown-up and still puts on a punch at each other's head for any small mistake. I go there and saw an unintentional mistake made by one of them causing me little harm in money and now I gift a punch to the same-- it may cause them daurmanasya but not **Bodily-Dukkha**(as the same is used to even harder punches).

Another eg. :: Two friends••• underwears••• Undertaker(WWE fighter) goes there along with media and saw••• and now gifts a punch to the same-- It `shall` result in Bodily-Dukkha and Daurmanasya(insult in public) as well.

Most important point to note here is:: **One can get rid of daurmanasya and bodily-dukkha by the 5th attainment out of 8 but cannot get rid of dukkha even by the 8th attainment.**

**Bodily-Dukkha**:: This is a restricted version of dukkha as  the ,`"final approval of perception part to be as pain for the sensations at physical_body level."`. **This also gets eradicated by 5th attainment.** This also may vary from person to person depending upon their **mental strength** to endure physical pain.

Here also to notice that, " daurmanasya might also generate bodily-dukkha". For eg., A beautiful wife starts cheating her husband who was too much attached to her. Upon learning of such act, his heart failed.

Again, a point to be noted-- Bodily-Dukkha might also result in daurmanasya. For eg., A person with an uncurable disease due to which person remains trapped under Bodily-Dukkha but with time it breaks down person mentally also, resulting in daurmanasya.

`As far as my experience of meditation practice goes, daurmanasya always results in bodily-dukkha.`

Above was **What is the difference between domanassa & dukkha?**

So, now comes the sweet-dish part-- ... :)

**Does dukkha or it's parts arise in enlightened beings?**

**Practical/Experience Answer**:: `I don't know, I am not an enlightened one`.

**In Theory::**

Simple Conclusive answer:: **Daurmanasya and Bodily-Dukkha** end with `merely` 5th attainment and dukkha ends with eradication of sabbasava, with eradication of ignorance, with establishment in equanimity and having awareness of such equanimity as well.

**Conclusion** :: **No, dukkha or it's parts are not there `within` Enlightened ones.**

**Reason** :: Back to 1st statement with basics, Noble Truths. Buddha said that his path eradicates dukkha(1st noble truth) by eradicating sabbasava, ignorance and establishing in equanimity with awareness of such equanimity.

This doesn't mean that they don't feel sensation but feeling is merely a feeling in itself. It's by the force of the impulse received by brain that they can say that this particular sensation will act as **bodily-dukkha or daurmanasya** for some other particular person but for them there is no such bodily-dukkha or dukkha itself. Therefore this mind and body might become to them as ,"Earth and stone... `reactionless`".

References for basic definitions.

[See info. regarding Attainments.](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.008.nypo.html)

If someone wants to check daurmanasya over [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/domanassa) and over [here too](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/daurmanasya#mahayana).

Dukkha over [here in Noble Truth](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Reference/Four-Noble-Truths.htm). Note here as how word 'dukkham' being used for 2 purposes. 1st as generalized and 2nd as bodily-dukkha. Also, [this dukkha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du%E1%B8%A5kha) might be of some interest to you(for me it was) along with this [11 headed dukkha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dukkha)

[8 worldly concerns](https://taralanka.org/stuff/8-worldly-concerns/)

Be Happy,

Answer (score 0):

The word 'dukkha' has three different meanings:

1. 'Pain', in relation to painful feelings.
2. 'Unsatisfactoriness', in relation to impermanent things unable to bring lasting happiness.
3. 'Suffering', in relation to how attachment is mental torment.

Enlightened beings experience painful feelings & the unsatisfactoriness of impermanent things but enlightened beings do not experience suffering.

When 'dukkha' means 'suffering, 'domanassa' is an attribute or component of suffering, as follows:

> Birth is suffering; old age is suffering; death is suffering; sorrow,
>   lamentation, pain, **sadness** and distress are **suffering**; not getting
>   what you wish for is suffering. In brief, the five grasping aggregates
>   are suffering.
>
> Jātipi dukkhā, jarāpi dukkhā, maraṇampi dukkhaṃ,
>   sokaparidevadukkha**domanass**upāyāsāpi **dukkhā**, yampicchaṃ na labhati
>   tampi dukkhaṃ; saṅkhittena pañcupādānakkhandhā dukkhā.
>
> And what is **sadness**?
>
> Katamañcāvuso, **domanassa**ṃ?
>
> Mental pain, mental displeasure, the painful, unpleasant feeling
>   that’s born from mind contact.
>
> Yaṃ kho, āvuso, cetasikaṃ dukkhaṃ cetasikaṃ asātaṃ manosamphassajaṃ
>   dukkhaṃ asātaṃ vedayitaṃ,
>
> This is called sadness.
>
> idaṃ vuccatāvuso: ‘domanassaṃ’.
>
> MN 141
>
> ---
>
> Birth is a condition for old age and death, sorrow, lamentation, pain,
>   **sadness** and distress to come to be.
>
> jātipaccayā jarāmaraṇaṃ sokaparidevadukkha**domanass**upāyāsā sambhavanti.
>
> That is how this entire mass of **suffering** originates.
>
> Evametassa kevalassa **dukkha**kkhandhassa samudayo hoti.
>
> SN 12.2